# how to remove single uploaded file from jQuery in multiple file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, multiple-file-upload

I've searched everywhere and still don't get what I want.

I've following input field.

```
<div class="form-group gallery-add-button">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="images">Image Gallery</label>
    <div class="gallery-item-wrapper-0">
        <input name="images[]" type="file" multiple class="filestyles gallery-images" id="photo-gallery" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I've made image preview and on a remove button click, image preview is removed. In this case, I want to remove uploaded image from file upload field as well. Is there any way to achieve this.

I've found a way to remove all uploaded files but not a particular image.

Any kind of help is appreciated and if you need further information then feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I have a example delete image hope it will help you.

```js
 // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    var htmlImage =  '<div>';
                        htmlImage = htmlImage +  '<img  src="'+event.target.result+'" />';  
                        htmlImage = htmlImage +  '<input onclick="removeImage($(this))" type="button" value="Delete" />'; 
                        htmlImage = htmlImage +  '</div>';        
                    $($.parseHTML(htmlImage)).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };
    
    function removeImage(item) {
      //alert(item);
       item.parent().remove();
    }
    
    $('#photo-gallery').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group gallery-add-button">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="images">Image Gallery</label>
    <div class="gallery-item-wrapper-0">
        <input name="images[]" type="file" multiple class="filestyles gallery-images" id="photo-gallery" />
        
        <div class="gallery"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I click delete button there is still file name on the side of browse button

Comment: I think you should set image name is empty in event change. ("#photo-gallery").val('');

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code fast, hope it help
if it was what you need and you need help, I will do

```js
var files=[];
$("#photo-gallery").change(function(){
 for(var i=0;i<this.files.length;i++){
  files.push(this.files[i]);
 }
 refreshFiles();
  $(this).val('');
});
function refreshFiles(){
 for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
  $("#result").append('<div class="img-div"><span>'+(i+1)+'. '+files[i].name+'</span><a href="#" title="delete" class="delete-image" image-id="'+i+'">x</a></div>');
 }
}
$(document).on('click','.delete-image',function(){
 var id=parseInt($(this).attr("image-id"));
 files.splice(id,1);
 $("#result").empty();
 refreshFiles();
});
$(document).on('click','a',function(){
 if($(this).attr("href")==="#"){
  return false;
 }
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family:arial;
}
#result{
 margin:4px 0;
}
.img-div{
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 width:200px;
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 margin:4px 0;
 border:1px solid #999;
 border-radius:6px;
 padding:0 8px;
}
.delete-image{
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 margin-left:20px;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:0 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="form-group gallery-add-button">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="images">Image Gallery</label>
    <div class="gallery-item-wrapper-0">
        <input name="images[]" type="file" multiple class="filestyles gallery-images" id="photo-gallery" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already made the remove button to remove preview but when I submit the form removed images are still submitted. if you know such thing can be acheived then you are heartly welcome to give suggestions.

Comment: in this example it will be deleted, just loop files in your form data not file input

Comment: let me write the full example and post it

Comment: Okay, take your time :D

Answer (score 0):

this is the full example and I tested it and it works
sure you cant test upload here but try it in your local server

```js
var files=[];
$("#photo-gallery").change(function(){
 for(var i=0;i<this.files.length;i++){
  files.push(this.files[i]);
 }
 refreshFiles();
});
function refreshFiles(){
 for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
  $("#result").append('<div class="img-div"><span>'+(i+1)+'. '+files[i].name+'</span><a href="#" title="delete" class="delete-image" image-id="'+i+'">x</a></div>');
 }
}
$(document).on('click','.delete-image',function(){
 var id=parseInt($(this).attr("image-id"));
 files.splice(id,1);
 $("#result").empty();
 refreshFiles();
});
$(document).on('click','a',function(){
 if($(this).attr("href")==="#"){
  return false;
 }
});
$(document).on('click','#submit',function(){
  if(files.length===0){
    return false;
  }
 var fd=new FormData();
 for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
  fd.append('img_'+i,files[i]);
 }
 $.ajax({
  url:"upload-images.php",
  method:"post",
  cache:false,
  dataType:'json',
  processData:false,
  contentType:false,
  data: fd,
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.img-div{
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 width:300px;
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 margin:4px 0;
 border:1px solid #999;
 border-radius:6px;
 padding:0 8px;
}
.delete-image{
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 margin-left:20px;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:0 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group gallery-add-button">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="images">Image Gallery</label>
    <div class="gallery-item-wrapper-0">
        <input name="images[]" type="file" multiple class="filestyles gallery-images" id="photo-gallery" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
<br>
<button id="submit">submit image</button>
```

and in you upload-images.php

```
foreach($_FILES as $file){
    //your code
}
```